# Export a VisNetwork plot to Gephi

Tags: r, shiny, gephi, visnetwork

My R/Shiny application generates network plots using VisNetwork. I need to export them to Gephi. What is the best way? Node colors, line width, background color (and aesthetics in general) are not important. I want to export the data. In Gephi I should get a similar plot.

According to [Gephi's documentation](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/) optimal formats are GEFX (edge weight, hierarchy and XML structure) or CSV (edge list / matrix). However, VisNetwork does not export these formats. Gephi can export a JSON file which can be opened with VisNetwork, but the contrary isn't possible. VisNetwork has `visNetwork(gephi = 'network.json')` but it does not export a JSON file, only import. `visExport()` only allows to export an image (png/jpg/pdf).

VisNetwork plot:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, label = paste("Label", 1:10),
   group = sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace = TRUE))

edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,5,10), to = c(1,2,10))
network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "400px", width = "100%")

visNetwork(gephi = 'network.json') #does not work
```

I will probably have to code a function that writes graph data into a text file. What is the best way to do so? Should I privilege a specific format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is a bit late but I will try to help anyway. Gephi reads interactions from CSV files quite well. So:

### R

You example is almost ok, just a litte change in the edges **columns name**:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, label = paste("Label", 1:10), 
   group = sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace = TRUE))

edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,5,10), to = c(1,2,10))
colnames(edges)<-c('source', 'target')
```

Then you should export as CSV:

```
write.csv(edges,'edges.csv')
write.csv(nodes,'nodes.csv')
```

### Gephi

Then, we go to gephi and:

File -> import spreadsheet

Please note:

1. You will have to import edges and nodes one file at a time
2. You will have to import both csv files to the same "workspace", or you will have two different graphs (empty edges and empty nodes)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to export the graph as one file from R to Gephi, you can write it to GraphML like so:

```
igraph::write_graph(graph, format = c("graphml"))
```

Then import it into Gephi.

Answer (score 1):

Soo after a few days I had no answer and dug more into it. Indeed, there is no way ot export directly data from a VisNetwork plot to Gephi. The most efficient way I found was to hard-write into a GEXF file. It's a bit tedious but your data will be loaded into Gephi without any concern.

Comment: Not sure why you think it is _tedious_ but I think GEXF is kind of a standard and a bunch of platforms support it. Gephi can read GEXF without complains...